# Python Pandas - Odds Ratio with Scipy (P Value = 0?)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am trying to calculate the Odds Ratio of a 2 x 2 grid (below)

```
    Lower       Higher
A   11772336    18837138
B   3624890     4263509
```

I have done this code to get the Odds Ratio:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
table = df.values
reversedTable = table[::-1]

oddsratio, pvalue = stats.fisher_exact(reversedTable)
print("OddsR: ", oddsratio, "p-Value:", pvalue)
```

The output is:

```
OddsR:  1.3604416468907712 p-Value: 0.0
```

If I use an online calculator I get a P value of <0.0001

Is there a way of not having the P Value being rounded down in my code? Or am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the z score for the log odds ratio is 382.246, and the associated two-tailed p-value is 3.169 × 10<sup>-31731</sup>. This is smaller than the smallest positive value that can be represented with a 64-bit float (2<sup>−1074</sup>), which is what `fisher_exact` returns for the p-value.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you! is there a way of increasing the size of the value that it can hold? I am writing a statistical report and I thought I would use Odds Ratio, however anything I do I have to back up with Python Code...... if it only shows 0.0 then I can't really use it.

Comment: Python does not provide arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic out of the box. You would probably need to use a third-party library (e.g., [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/)) and do the p-value computation yourself instead of relying on `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the time you have taken to respond.